# Unit testing with portable library for Windows Phone 7 and 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, mvvm-light, portable-class-library

I currently have a VS2012 solution with a WP71 project and a WP8 project. Each of these projects reference a Portable Class Library project where I keep the view models. I also have a Unit Test project that references the PCL and contains tests for the view models.

The problem I'm having is when I compile the unit test project I get the following error:

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'
```

All of the projects, including the unit test project, reference the Portable.MvvmLightLibs NuGet package.

After looking around for this assembly I noticed that there are different versions, one for WP8, one for Silverlight 4, etc. Out of all these versions I'm not sure which to use.

The unit test project is targeting .NET Framework 4.5, so I added the System.Windows assembly for that version which works, but I then get the following error:

```
 error : CA0001 : Could not resolve reference to System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes
```

Seeing as this is a code analysis error I'm tempted to simply ignore this and carry on, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to solve this or whether it is safe to ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured a way to solve the problem.

To get the test project to compile I had to add the **System.Windows.dll** assembly from:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71**

But, adding it using the Add Reference dialog automatically adds the .NET 4.5 version even if I browsed directly to the folder. To fix this I opened the *.csproj for the test project and replaced the line:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows"/>
```

with

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Windows.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This ensured that the 2.0.5.0 version was referenced instead of the .NET 4.5 version. The problem with this approach is certain types conflict with other assemblies, namely the System.dll, but seeing as I'm only testing view models from a Portable Class Library, I'm not all that bothered.

Ideally the test project would also be a Portable Class Library, but I've not got round to testing that.

One other issue was I tend to have warnings show up as errors when building in release mode, so this always fails because there will always be a warning complaining about naming clashes with System.dll.